# Ajax request is not working with Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm now self-practicing Codeigniter with the help of internet. I'm able to create almost all operations now , but today I'm tried to fetch data using ajax call. Nothing is retrieving from database, but while debugging with Chrome's debugger, no error is showing. I'm hitting my head for six hours for this problem.I tried everything and reached finally here.

This is my **Model**

```
public function member_id($postData)
      {
          $response = array();
           if($postData['member_id'] ){

   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where('member_id', $postData['member_id']);
   $q = $this->db->get('tbl_test');
   $response = $q->result_array();

  }

  return $response;
      }
```

**Controller**

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->_init();
    }
private function _init()
    {
        $this->output->set_template('default');
        $this->load->css('assets/themes/default/css/my.css');
        $this->load->css('assets/themes/default/css/bootstrap.css');
        $this->load->css('assets/themes/default/css/bootstrap-theme.css');


    }

public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
        $this->load->view('pages/home',$data);
    }
public function feeDetails()
    {
       $postData  = $this->input->post();

       $this->load->model('Model');

       $data = $this->Model->member_id($postData);

           echo json_encode($data);
     }
```

**View**

```
  <input class="form-control in2" id="txtmemid" placeholder="Member id " name="txtmemid" value="" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="btnmemfeeview" class="btn btn-default ho showser fl ">Search</button>

   Bill No: <span id='bno'></span><br/>
   Bill date: <span id='bdate'></span><br/>
   Member id: <span id='mid'></span><br/>
```

and finally this is my **ajax**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#btnmemfeeview").click(function(){
    var member_id = $('#txtmemid').val();
    $.ajax({
     url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/Pages/feeDetails',
     method: 'post',
    data: {member_id: member_id},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(response){
      var len = response.length;

      if(len > 0){
       // Read values

       var bno = response.BILL_NO;
       var bdate = response.BILL_DATE;
       var mid = response.MEMBER_ID ;

       $('#bno').text(bno);
       $('#bdate').text(bdate);
       $('#mid').text(mid);

      }else{

       $('#bno').text('');
       $('#bdate').text('');
       $('#mid').text('');
      }

     }
   });
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: There are no form tag try with form.

Comment: have you tried `$('#bno').html(bno);` instead of `$('#bno').text(bno);`?

Comment: Are you getting result in network tab?

Comment: Result is showing while debugging.

Comment: share your result

Comment: Please check here, https://i.imgur.com/eoyEGvv.png

Comment: B. Desai - Did you get any clue?